# Replica island only has one set of images, why?

Tags: android, image, opengl-es, bitmap

When I looked at:
http://replicaisland.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/res/drawable/
and found it only had one set of images, I wondered why this was. Obviously I missed something because I thought everyone needed three sets of images so that you could support all android devices. (Phones) I have not looked through all the code yet, but **does Chris just resize the images or not support other devices?**

Comment: This question is inappropriate for StackOverflow. It has nothing to do with programming; it's a question about why a developer decided to design their project the way they did. This is not an actual programming question, and is off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obviously I missed something because I thought everyone needed three sets of images so that you could support all android devices.

Having *four* sets of images (`-ldpi`, `-mdpi`, `-hdpi`, `-xhdpi`) is generally a good idea... if you are using the widget-based framework, and for images used by the OS (e.g., launcher icons).

If you are writing a game -- particularly one like Replica Island, which uses OpenGL -- you are probably going to use different techniques. In Replica Island's case, it appears that `DrawableBitmap` handles scaling "between the bitmap resolution and the display resolution".